# creating a loop for css animation

Tags: css

I am using the following code to change the background color of an element using css animations. Is there a way to change this in order to make it loop continuously?

```
    #circle {
      animation: colorchange 10s;
      -webkit-animation: colorchange 10s;
    }

    @keyframes colorchange
    {
      0%   {background: red;}
      25%  {background: yellow;}
      50%  {background: blue;}
      75%  {background: green;}
      100% {background: red;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes colorchange
    {
      0%   {background: red;}
      25%  {background: yellow;}
      50%  {background: blue;}
      75%  {background: green;}
      100% {background: red;}
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use:

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [animation documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp) you can indicate the number of iteration.

With the property `animation-iteration-count` or in the `animation` definition.

```css
#circle {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  animation: colorchange 10s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: colorchange 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes colorchange
{
  0%   {background: red;}
  25%  {background: yellow;}
  50%  {background: blue;}
  75%  {background: green;}
  100% {background: red;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorchange
{
  0%   {background: red;}
  25%  {background: yellow;}
  50%  {background: blue;}
  75%  {background: green;}
  100% {background: red;}
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` to your `#circle` div's css block as following:

```
#circle {
    animation: colorchange 10s;
    -webkit-animation: colorchange 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

The animation-iteration-count property specifies the number of times an animation should be played.